# Closing a tab for a record opens a Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

First time using this so please be patient with me. I am new to the development side of things as I generally just do administration work. However I am starting to get my feet wet with development and have run into an issue.

When there is a record tab opened within Salesforce (see image) upon closing it, instead of the record tab closing, it will open a VF page that I created.

[image: open record tab]

Here is code for the VF page and for the apex class that accompanies it.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="HLResourceCenterURL" action="{!urlRedirection}">

</apex:page>
```

Apex class:

```
public class HLResourceCenterURL {

    public PageReference urlRedirection() {

      string url = 'https://sites.google.com/{websiteurl}/hlresourcecenter/home';

      PageReference page = new PageReference(url);
      page.setRedirect(true);
      return page;
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: is this within a console app?

Comment: I actually discovered the issue. Since the tab that was being used to launch the resource center was the last in line, anytime another tab was closed SF moves to the last tab in the list causing the resource tab to fire the apex class (working as intended.) I moved the resource tab further up the list of tabs so that it was no longer the last one and thus not popping when a tab was closed.

Comment: you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered the issue. Since the tab that was being used to launch the resource center was the last in line, anytime another tab was closed SF moves to the last tab in the list causing the resource tab to fire the apex class (working as intended.) I moved the resource tab further up the list of tabs so that it was no longer the last one and thus not popping when a tab was closed.